# Accessing a ModelMap list through JavaScript in JSP

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a List of People Objects added to my ModelMap. A person has a name and a date. I know I can access the list by doing the following in the html part of the JSP

```
 ${peopleList}
```

However I want to loop through this list in the JSP in a JavaScript tag, I have tried the following but I am having no luck, and for testing I have just been doing an alert.

```
 var people = "${peopleList}"
 alert(people[0].name);
```

How can I access these properties in JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close to the solution, but what you did wrong is a java `List` object cannot be converted to a javascript list object directly with `var people = "${peopleList}"`. Instead, you can loop through the `List` object and create the javascript variables manually using [JSTL](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl/1.2):

Import the jstl core taglib at the top of the jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Then inside the script tag, create your peopleList:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var peopleList = new Array();

<c:forEach items="${peopleList}" var="ppl">
    var people = new Object();
    people.name = '${ppl.name}';
    people.date = '${ppl.date}';

    peopleList.push(people);
</c:forEach>

if(peopleList.length > 0){
    alert(peopleList[0].name);
}

</script>
```

Comment: is c:foreach can put in javascript ?